# Firebase UI Recyclerview OnClick Not Working, tried everything. And it is not a duplicate question please

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm trying to add a Firebase Recyclerview in my Android App. When I add, all the data is getting fetched from Firestore normally, but when it comes to handle onClick event, it is not working at all.

### Things I followed:

- Added Interface with method.
- Implemented interface in my TipsActivity.java

Here is the code:

### TipsActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.paging.PagedList;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.util.Log;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;



public class TipsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FirestoreTipsAdapter.OnListItemClick {

   FirestoreTipsAdapter firestoreTipsAdapter;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tips);

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("DailyTips").document("MyTips").collection("Tips");

    PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
            .setPageSize(5)
            .build();

    FirestorePagingOptions<TipsModel> firestorePagingOptions = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<TipsModel>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(query,config,TipsModel.class)
            .build();

    firestoreTipsAdapter = new FirestoreTipsAdapter(firestorePagingOptions,this,this);

       recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firestoreTipsAdapter);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Show up bruh!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.d("AT_LEAST","You should work");
}
}
```

And here goes my:

### FirestoreTipsAdapter.java

```
package com.mycompany.company;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingOptions;

public class FirestoreTipsAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<TipsModel, FirestoreTipsAdapter.TipsViewHolder> {

    private OnListItemClick onListItemClick;
    Context context;

    public FirestoreTipsAdapter(@NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<TipsModel> options,OnListItemClick onListItemClick,Context context) {
        super(options);
        this.onListItemClick = onListItemClick;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TipsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull TipsModel model) {
        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TipsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new TipsViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class TipsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView title,description;


        public TipsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Are you working bro?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onListItemClick.onItemClick();
        }
    }
    public interface OnListItemClick{
        void onItemClick();
    }
}
```

### Here is the code of list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tipCardView"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#E2E0EE"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Description" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/curveshape"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tips"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:alpha="0.2"
        />


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Note: I'm able to fetch data from Firestore, it is showing data properly.**
[image]
Please help. I followed all other answers from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you mean that you're not even seeing that `Toast` in the `OnClickListener` on `itemView`? Also, please post the `list_item` layout.

Comment: You're not calling `startListening` anywhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744498/android-recyclerview-not-working/46774532#46774532

Comment: Hi @Mike. Yes. I'm neither getting Toast nor Log.d. Also, I've added all other code, please have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I agree with your point. But in the documentation it is written that either call startListening or stopListening or give the LifecycleOwner (I gave lifecycleowner).
-
In 3.x you must explicitly call startListening() and stopListening() or pass a LifecycleOwner to the options builder.

Comment: Remove the `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` attributes from the `<LinearLayout>`.

Comment: Hey @MikeM. Thank you!
Can you please write this comment as a separate answer so that I could mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the given setup, the `OnClickListener` is being set on the `ViewHolder`'s `itemView`, which will be the root `View` in its layout, which is the `CardView`. However, the `clickable` and `focusable` attributes set on the `LinearLayout` cause it to get first grabs on touch events, so it's basically intercepting them before the `CardView` would handle them to respond to a click. There's no listener on the `LinearLayout`, though, so nothing happens.

Assuming that you want the entire item `View` clickable, simply remove the `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` attributes from the `<LinearLayout>`. With no `clickable` or `focusable` children, the `CardView` will then end up registering the click.

If instead you might want only a certain child clickable – e.g., the `LinearLayout` – then you would set the `OnClickListener` on that child, rather than the whole `CardView`. You still wouldn't need those attributes anywhere, though, if that's to be the only clickable child or grandchild. Those attributes usually aren't necessary in basic, relatively flat layouts, like that for your list items.