# RecyclerView OnClickListener not firing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I aim to make a simple to-do list and for that I have used RecyclerView. My issue is that the OnClickListener() in the RecyclerView adapter class is not getting called. I have no idea why this is happening.

P.S I am fairly new to Android Development so please excuse any stupid mistake I have made.

RecyclerView adapter class:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_task.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_todo.view.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class TodoAdapter(val list: List<TodoModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position],position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Log.e("dbg","click")
            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.context,"This should be called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return list[position].id
    }

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        fun bind(todoModel: TodoModel,pos:Int) {
            with(itemView) {
                txtShowTitle.text = todoModel.title
                txtShowTask.text = todoModel.description
                txtShowCategory.text = todoModel.category
                updateTime(todoModel.time)
                updateDate(todoModel.date)

            }

        }

        private fun updateTime(time: Long) {
            //4:55 AM
            val myformat = "h:mm a"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myformat)
            itemView.txtShowTime.text = sdf.format(Date(time))

        }

        private fun updateDate(time: Long) {
            //Mon, 5 Jan 2020
            val myformat = "EEE, d MMM yyyy"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myformat)
            itemView.txtShowDate.text = sdf.format(Date(time))

        }
    }

}
```

item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#818181"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/allDetailsTextColor">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtShowCategory"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="Task Title" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtShowTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Task Subtitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/spinner_item_background"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            tools:text="Category" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtShowTask"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtShowTime"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:text="22-12-2017" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShowTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtShowTask"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:text="22:12 AM" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62367910.

Comment: The issue mentioned in the link is different from mine. I want my OnClickListener to fire but it is not firing.

Comment: I'm sorry? How do you possibly think that's not related? It's asking the exact same thing that you are.

Comment: I think the link previously linked to a different issue. Nevertheless, it worked via your solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, can I call startActivity() from that OnClickListener? If yes, how?

Comment: You generally don't want your `Adapter` doing things like that internally. The `Activity` should be handling that. Here's a link to a simple example of how to set up a callback from the `Adapter` to your `Activity`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40584424. They're just showing a `Toast` in that example, but you can easily replace that with your `startActivity()` call.